# How to create a skype for business meeting from IBM Notes Calendar?

Tags: email, lotus-notes, api, skype-for-business

I need to integrate the Skype for business meetings button into IBM Notes calendar

Is there a Skype API that I can use to programmatically do this

Thanks

Thomas

Answer (score 0):

UCWA is an api for that

Create an application 
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/skype/ucwa/createanapplication

and then

Schedule an online meeting
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/skype/ucwa/scheduleanonlinemeeting

Comment: Welcome to Super User! External links can break or be unavailable, in which case your answer would not be useful.  Please include the essential information within your answer and use the link for attribution and further reading.  Thanks.